How to enable the access to cloud run from a cloud function when the cloud run's ingress is set as internal
I have a cloud run R, which can be accessed as XXX.a.run.app if ingress setting is all. When changing its ingress to be internal, I found that a VM instance can still access XXX.a.run.app, but my cloud function F cannot access it any more.
I know using a load balancer can make it work. But that's cause some efficiency loss. How can I directly access R from F once I set the ingress to internal if possible?
I tried to add vpc connector to the cloud function F, though it does not seem to help. Note that the cloud run R and cloud function F are using the same service account.

Did Guillaume answer helped you to resolve your issue, If the answer is helpful, please click "Accept Answer" and kindly upvote it. If you have extra questions about this answer, please click "Comment" , thanks

The serverless VPC connector is the right solution. But, there is a trick! the a.run.app domain is public. That way, the traffic is publicly routed!
Having this in mind, have a look on your egress parameter (the traffic being routed to your serverless VPC connector). It should be set to internal, meaning only the internal traffic (having a non public IP) will be routed to the serverless VPC connector.
However, as I said, the a.run.app is public!! Therefore, set the egress to "all traffic" to route publicly and publicly addressable IPs. And it will work!
